# matrix inequality proof [completion of squares]

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality, control-theory

Can someone help me to prove this?

$\begin{bmatrix} 0 & B^\top W^\top \\ WB & 0 \end{bmatrix} \leq
\begin{bmatrix} B^\top Q B & 0 \\0 & W^\top Q^{-1}W \end{bmatrix}$

with $Q$ positive definite matrix of suitable dimensions. I guess it comes from the completion of squares. Thanks! How can I found an upper bound forthe following matrix, based on the former result?

$\delta \begin{bmatrix} B+ B^\top & W^\top B^\top \\ WB & 0  \end{bmatrix}$, with $\delta \in \mathbb{R} $.

Comment: What is the definition of '$\leq$' here?

Comment: @Indominus As bi-linear functionals

Comment: @Laura "Dimention" should be written as "Dimension"

Comment: @Indominus  $A \leq B$ means that $A-B$ is positive semidefinite

Comment: Thanks @user18537 for the correction

Answer (score 4):

The matrix $\begin{bmatrix}  B^\top Q B & -B^\top W^\top \\WB & W^\top Q^{-1} W\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}  -B^\top  & 0 \\ 0 & W^\top \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}  Q & I \\ I & Q^{-1} \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}  -B  & 0 \\ 0 & W\end{bmatrix}$ is positive semidefinite if Q is positive definite (Q can not be positive semidefinite because Q is invertible).

Comment: I guess you still need to do some more work to show the middle matrix on the right hand side is positive semidefinite, right?

Comment: As a complement to your answer, let's write $$\begin{bmatrix} Q  & I \\ I & Q^{-1} \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} I & 0 \\ Q^{-1} & I \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} Q & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} I & Q^{-1} \\ 0 & I \end{bmatrix}.$$ proving that $\begin{bmatrix} Q  & I \\ I & Q^{-1} \end{bmatrix}$ is positive semidefinite (and not invertible). Of course, we need assume $Q$ is also symmetric.

Comment: @Zhanxiong Any positive definite matrix under consideration is clearly symmetric

Answer (score 0):

Do a difference and use Gaussian Elimination Method for blocked Matrices.

Comment: may I ask you to write explicitly the computations? thanks!

Comment: @Laura i'm just lazy to type matrices, the right - the left and eliminate (2,1), (1,2) block by multiplying the first row $W(B^tQ)^{-1}$ and adding it to the second row, then multiplying the first column by sth and add it to the second column, sth can be left there without computation as the final matrix is symmetric, and the (1,2) block will vanish. Then the (2,2) block will go to 0, the (1,1) block will be $B^tQB$, which is positive by your assumption.~~~~~~~~~~~QED

Comment: Ok, or we can prove it in this way. $ \begin{bmatrix} B^\top Q B & -B^\top W^\top  \\ WB & W^\top Q^{-1} W  \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}  -B^\top & 0 \\ 0 &W^\top \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} Q & I \\ I & Q^{-1} \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}  -B & 0 \\ 0 &W \end{bmatrix}$ is positive semidefinite if Q is positive semidefinite.

Comment: @Laura You need to learn how to deal with blocked matrices directly, it's important indeed !